# how to get urls for scrapy from external app

Tags: python, django, scrapy

Given your standard scrapy app:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

How do I pull urls from an external source? Am I using a web service? Am I using django or a database connection?

Is scrapy expecting us to hardcode this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `urls` variable that you have in `start_requests` with the list of the URLs you want to scrape. It doesn't have to be hardcoded.

For example, if you do it in Django, assuming you have a model ScrapeUrl with field model

`urls = ScrapeUrl.objects.values_list('url', flat=True)`

If it's from an API, you can use `requests` to fetch them for you.

Don't forget to setup Django though before accessing any model.